# Why doesn't the shell command find . -name "*.txt" | rm remove all .txt files in the current directory?

Tags: shell, posix, pipe

I am new to the shell. I tried to use the following command to remove all .txt files in the current directory.

```
find . -name "*.txt" | rm
```

I realize this isn't the most straightforward way to remove all .txt files -- it was just an experiment with pipes. But it just returns usage information for rm... doesn't do what I expected.

Wherein lies my misunderstanding? Thank you!

Comment: `rm *.txt` would be a lot simpler...

Comment: @DaoWen But that's not recursive

Comment: Note the useful `exec` option of find. It may help here

Comment: Thank you. As I indicated in my original post, I realize it's a convoluted command. I am not asking for an easier way, I am asking why it doesn't work as expected, because the fact that it doesn't, betrays a misunderstanding of pipes -- my question is, why doesn't piping to rm achieve what I want? What is wrong with my understanding of pipes? :)

Comment: Pipe doesn't pass stdout as arguments to next command and rm is expecting filenames as arguments. There is xargs utility that converts piped stdin to command args

Comment: There's one more misunderstanding here: The asterisk ("*") can be resolved by both find and the shell. If resolved by the shell, think about what it turns the commandline of find into! Also, another thing to put into your BASH toolbox: `rm $(find . -name '*txt')`.

Comment: The pipes connects `stdout` of the left side to the `stdin` on the right side of the `|`. That's mean: the program at right side **must** read the stdin, for example the `tr` `sed` and many programs. The `rm` isn't designed to read from `stdin` (IMHO because it would be to dangerous).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The command substitution is OK, but you should tell: it works only with filenames "without" spaces.... ;)

Comment: True, @jm666. I'd say using "-exec rm .." is probably a better way, plus of course proper quoting therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) to treat the piped-in data as arguments:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs rm
```

Of course, there are easier ways to do this:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec rm {} \;

rm *.txt
```

Note that the latter only deletes files in the current directory, whereas using `find` does a recursive search.

Comment: `-exec rm {} \;` will launch one `rm` process for every file, is you use `rm {} +` it will get as many files as `ARGMAX` allows and passes that to `rm`, ie. it's a lot faster.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. Konstantin V. Salikhov's elaboration also helped clarify: "Pipe doesn't pass stdout as arguments to next command and rm is expecting filenames as arguments. There is xargs utility that converts piped stdin to command args"

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the `-exec` argument:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec rm {} +
```

Little known bonus fact about `-exec`:

People often use `-exec rm {} \;` this will launch one `rm` process for every file, is you use `rm {} +` it will get as many files as `ARG_MAX` allows and passes that to `rm`, ie. it's a lot faster, especially for many files.
[This is in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) and portable.

Comment: +1 - I didn't know about the `+` option, that's neat!